# javascript - validation focus on error, AND referring to THIS element

Tags: javascript, validation, element

sorry for the hyper basic question,

I'm doing a validation onChange - it behaves as expected to a point - and it just allows you to continue...

here's my 'simple' requirements...
a field has a RANGE of values it will accept. (i.e. 0-3, 1-5, 1-10...)
I'm calling a function onChange, when some value other than one within the range is entered...
I want an alert, and the focus to remain in that field (maybe even clear the erroneous value)

The code I have - works to the point it sends an alert - 
HOWEVER once you click 'ok' to the alert - the focus has moved to the next element, and the 'bad' data IS STILL in the field...

I KNOW there's a way to refer to the element that is 'calling' the function, but I don't know the syntax, but it should be easy to focus and clear the element??? right???

the code:

```
<form name="FRM_SCORING" id="FRM_SCORING" action=""  >
<input type="text" name="AOS1" onchange="checkrange(this.value,0,1);">
<input type="text" name="AOS2" onchange="checkrange(this.value,0,3);">
</form>

<script>
function checkrange(object_value, min_value, max_value) {
//---  remove leading and trailing spaces 
var trimmed_object_value = trim(object_value);
var temp_object_value    = trimmed_object_value;

alert ("You've entered a value that is not allowed. \nCheck the range of numbers allowed for this 'answer'.");

//---  if less than minimum or greater than maximum, return false  ---//
if ( isNaN(trimmed_object_value) || 
         (trimmed_object_value < min_value) || (trimmed_object_value > max_value)
       ) {
       alert ("You've entered a value that is not allowed.");
    return false;
} 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

Either pass the element as another argument, or use [`call` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) to set explicitly what `this` should refer to inside the function: `checkrange(this.value,0,1).call(this)`.